# How to check a regex at a specific index in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to do a regex match at a specific position in Typescript.

Here's what I have tried.

```
var str = "0123ABC789"
function matchesAt(rgx: RegExp, s : string, i : number) : string | void {
    rgx.lastIndex = i

    console.log(rgx.exec(s));
}

matchesAt(/(ABC)/g, str, 4 )
```

In essence, I am trying to recreate the String.startsWith(string, number) method, but with a regex inside - instead of another string.

I am expecting that the function should only match when the index is 4. any other number should return a nil.

Comment: Why do you have the `^` then?

Comment: just randomly trying out all options. If I do `matchesAt(/(ABC)/g, str, 2 )', that also matches - but I only want it to match at that specific index.

Editing out the ^ now

Comment: So why not use `slice` on the string? [It's pretty simple](https://tsplay.dev/WzPl4N).

Comment: I am writing a parser. creating a slice containing the full source, for every char of the source will be too much overhead.

Comment: How...? I just showed that it's adding `.slice(i)`? (did not downvote)

Comment: Essentially, I need to loop over a source file and will do a regex match on every char. I think that the use of slice here ` console.log(rgx.exec(s.slice(i)));` will create a new string containing pretty much the entire source - as many number of times as there are characters in the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249458/discussion-between-cats-and-rishav-sharan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [sticky flag `y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky):

> The `y` flag indicates that the regex attempts to match the target string only from the index indicated by the `lastIndex` property (and unlike a global regex, does not attempt to match from any later indexes).

```js
function matchesAt(rgx, s, i) {
    rgx.lastIndex = i;
    return rgx.test(s); // use .test to get boolean result
}

var str = "0123ABC789";
console.log(matchesAt(/ABC/gy, str, 4)); // true
console.log(matchesAt(/ABC/gy, str, 3)); // false!
```

Comment: Would like to understand why this answer is found not useful?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was missing! No idea who marked as not useful

Answer (score 2):

You can check if matched string length plus i is equal as following lastIndex:

```
function matchesAt(rgx: RegExp, s : string, i : number) : string | void {
    rgx.lastIndex = i
    let isMatching = rgx.exec(s);

    if (isMatching && isMatching?.length > 1 && rgx.lastIndex - isMatching[1]?.length == i)
        return s;
    return void null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a pretty innovative way of going about the problem.